# Keep getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with maven project in vscode?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

It is just a simple maven project with 1 dependency. I can compile it with not error but when I run it, it won't work. I am guessing that it is some problem with classpath, as when I manually passed all dependecies classpath to the commandline, it runs fine.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Tsm.png)

Also I tried to open the project in idea, and it worked fine.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Remove the dependency and delete its installation, after **clean java language server workspace** from command palette, click **Maven: Add a dependency** to re-add it then rebuild project, does this help?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT Nope, this does not help. VScode runs java and send classpath option by a temp argfile. I tried copy the content of the argfile into command line and it worked, but somehow java just cannot read classpath from the argfile.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This error must be related to dependency installation, cause it works well in my project. Please create a new maven project then try again.